# zsh partially completion in aptitude/wajig

Tags: zsh

I'm using wajig to install packages, however when i've changed my shell to zsh it turned out that zsh doesn't list all packages in completion list, for ex.

```
apt-get install octave[TAB]
```

(about 70 completions)
but when i try

```
wajig install octave[TAB]
```

or

```
aptitude install octave[TAB]
```

zsh shows only 19 completions

other shells i've tested (bash, fish) shows all ~70 completions in all 3 cases.
So is there any way to 'fix'  this completion in zsh?

Answer (score 2):

I get 73 entries for each of them. Check to make sure that you have completion functions called `_apt`, `_aptitude` and `_wajig` in your `zsh` completion function directory. Mine are in:

```
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Debian
```

Each of these functions is different, but they each call `_deb_packages` which is also in that directory.

Comment: hmm... i have these functions in this directory too, could you post your version of _wajig and _aptitude? I am not sure what should i change cause there is call to _deb_packages in it. paste-it.net/public/l71a52d <-- This is my default _wajig file

Comment: Your `_wajig` file is identical to mine. Since `_apt` calls `_deb_packages` with "avail" and the other functions call it with "uninstalled" I would do an `apt-get update` and see if that helps. (and maybe an `apt-get check` or `apt-get clean`)

Comment: still no improvement maybe i'll try to reconfigure whole zsh